# Error rotating canvas with values from an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

My aim in this program is to archive a way to properly show an array's values in a cavas, turning each value into a pixel's color.
   Despite the original task is done in the program's first step, when I try to turn the canvas an n-number of degrees, the canvas just dissapears from browser!

What could be wrong with this?

```
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <title>Rectangles</title>
         <style> 
         body {
            background: #dddddd;
         }

         #canvas {
            background: #eeeeee;
            border: thin solid #aaaaaa;
         }
      </style>
   </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id='canvas' width="200" height="200">
      Canvas not supported
    </canvas>

    <br>

    <button type="button"id="disminuir" onclick="Rotar()">Rotar</button>

    <script >
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');



    //GIRADOR



    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2); //Esto sitúa en el centro del canvas el origen de coordenadas



    //FIN GIRADOR




    var array = new Array2D(200,200);


    //MAIN

    for(i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<200; j++)
      {
      array[i][j]=i+j;
      document.write(array[i][j]);
      document.write("\n");
      var r,g,b;
      r = array[i][j];
      g=50;
      b=50;
      //La parte de dibujo
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",100)";
      ctx.fillRect( i, j, 1, 1 );

      }
    }

    //FUNCIONES

    function Array2D(NumOfRows,NumOfCols)
    {
    var k=new Array(NumOfRows);
    for (i = 0; i < k.length; ++i)
    k[i] = new Array(NumOfCols);
    return k; 
    }

    function Rotar(){
    //Rotamos el lienzo?
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180);

    for(i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<200; j++)
      {
      array[i][j]=i+j;
      document.write(array[i][j]);
      document.write("\n");
      var r,g,b;
      r = array[i][j];
      g=50;
      b=50;
      //La parte de dibujo
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+",100)";
      ctx.fillRect( i, j, 1, 1 );

      }
    }



    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Rotar` function is being called *after* the document finishes loading (presumably on a button click). That function contains `document.write` statements. Attempting to do a `document.write` on an already loaded web page causes the contents to clear out.

Replace your `document.write` statements with something like `console.log` or use `jQuery` to append the text on the body. Just make sure you append your text into a child element (like a `div`) to avoid refreshing the entire DOM tree with the `canvas` element.

Comment: Thaks. That was exactly the issue.